# The infinite X in Conway's game of life

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory, cellular-automata, infinite-games

In Conway's game of life, take the initial position to be two infinite diagonal lines of live cells, with a single cell in common. Does this thing converge to a stable configuration? I.e., is the state of each cell (or finite region) eventually periodic?

Comment: What kind of experimental evidence do you have for large finite approximations?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image]

What I get from an X of size $11121\times11121$ at just around the point where information travels to the tips.

Even from Xs ten times as long, there is Methuselah-like ebbing and flowing of debris near the center amid a pool of still lifes and blinkers still thousands of generations on.

[image]

Just going from experience working on the Busy Beaver of 5, I would imagine this question might be enormously difficult to settle, owing to the globally fractal and locally random nature of the picture.